# Passing a value from a controller to a file textbox

Tags: razor, model-view-controller

I'm trying to show the path of a file passed from a model in a file type textbox. The file path gets passed fine when it is a regular textbox but nothing gets passed when it is of type file.

I've tried adding it with jQuery also with no luck.

Any idea if this is possible?

Works `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.filpath)`

Doesn't work
`@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.filpath, new { type = "file" })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're talking about this:

```
<input type="file" />
```

This is not a text box. This is a [file upload control](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.file.html). There is no way to pre-populate its value - not allowed by browsers as it is a security risk. If you could pre-populate its value you would be able to upload any file from user's computer to your server.

Comment: Yeah I was, okay well that answers that. Thanks